# How to replace 0 in the nth column of all dataframe in a list with another value?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

I have a list of dataframes and I would like to replace 0 in the second column of all dataframes in that list.

Heres the minimal working example for the list of dataframes:

```
> named <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
> one <- c(0, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0)
> two <- c(1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 6)
> df <- data.frame(named, one, two)
> df1 <- data.frame(named, two, one)
> listed <- list(df, df1)
>
> listed
[[1]]
  named one two
1     1   0   1
2     2   2   0
3     3   0   3
4     4   4   0
5     5   5   0
6     6   0   6

[[2]]
  named two one
1     1   1   0
2     2   0   2
3     3   3   0
4     4   0   4
5     5   0   5
6     6   6   0
```

I can replace a column of a particular dataframe (second column of second dataframe in the following code) with `replace(listed[[2]][2], listed[[2]][2] == 0, 1)`.

But how do I do this for all the dataframes in the list? I tried:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  replace(listed[[i]][2], listed[[i]][2] == 0, -1)
}
```

But its obviously a terrible attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` -

```
listed <- lapply(listed, function(x) {x[2][x[2] == 0] <- -1;x})
```

Or to use `replace` and `for` loop assign the changed data back to list.

```
for (i in seq_along(listed)) {
  listed[[i]][2] <- replace(listed[[i]][2], listed[[i]][2] == 0, -1)
}

listed
#[[1]]
#  named one two
#1     1  -1   1
#2     2   2   0
#3     3  -1   3
#4     4   4   0
#5     5   5   0
#6     6  -1   6

#[[2]]
#  named two one
#1     1   1   0
#2     2  -1   2
#3     3   3   0
#4     4  -1   4
#5     5  -1   5
#6     6   6   0
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining the ```{x[2][x[2] == 0] <- -1;x}``` for me? Why do you have ```;x``` at the end? What is it for? Sorry, my basic is still pretty bad.

Comment: `x[2][x[2] == 0] <- -1` replaces the 0's with -1. The final `x` is to return the changed dataframe (with all columns) from `lapply` output. Try removing it from the code and see what you get back.

Comment: Got it. I didn't get to try the ```for``` loop in your answer, but the ```lapply``` works. It looks simpler too.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use column index in across

```r
library(tidyverse)

map(listed, ~.x %>% mutate(across(2, ~replace(., .== 0, -1))))

#> [[1]]
#>   named one two
#> 1     1  -1   1
#> 2     2   2   0
#> 3     3  -1   3
#> 4     4   4   0
#> 5     5   5   0
#> 6     6  -1   6
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   named two one
#> 1     1   1   0
#> 2     2  -1   2
#> 3     3   3   0
#> 4     4  -1   4
#> 5     5  -1   5
#> 6     6   6   0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` from tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

map(listed, ~ mutate_at(.x, .vars = colnames(.x)[length(colnames(.x))],
                        ~ case_when(. == 0 ~ -1, T ~ as.numeric(.))))
```

This code goes through each dataframe in `listed`, identifies only the last column, and changes the 0 values to -1, as in your for loop example.

Output:

```
[[1]]
  named one two
1     1   0   1
2     2   2  -1
3     3   0   3
4     4   4  -1
5     5   5  -1
6     6   0   6

[[2]]
  named two one
1     1   1  -1
2     2   0   2
3     3   3  -1
4     4   0   4
5     5   0   5
6     6   6  -1
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `na_if/replace_na`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
 map(listed, ~ .x %>% 
         mutate(across(2,  ~ replace_na(na_if(., 0), -1))))
[[1]]
  named one two
1     1  -1   1
2     2   2   0
3     3  -1   3
4     4   4   0
5     5   5   0
6     6  -1   6

[[2]]
  named two one
1     1   1   0
2     2  -1   2
3     3   3   0
4     4  -1   4
5     5  -1   5
6     6   6   0
```